# Joystick, gamepad or 3D mouse support in Three.js

Tags: user-interface, 3d, three.js, joystick, gamepad

An open question to the three.js community.

As far as I know, the Three.js framework has different "enhancements" like OrbitControls.js that allow us to use the mouse or a touchscreen to explore a 3D scene.

Now my question:

Is out there another "enhancement" for Three.js that allows the usage of joysticks, gamepads or 3D mouses? 
If not, how easy or difficult do you think it can be to implement their functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link by juagicre is useful.

Here are some more

1. This one checks that signals from your connected gamepad are being received:-
   [html5gamepad.com](http://html5gamepad.com/)
2. [html5rocks.com gamepad tester with image](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/gamepad-tester/tester.html)
3. [stemkoski html5 demo](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/#gamepad-test)
4. [stemkoski THREE.js demo](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mesh-Movement-Gamepad.html).
5. [html5rocks tuorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/)

I just picked up a cheap unbranded USB gamepad in a thrift shop today.  Using Firefox 38.0.5 or Chrome 47.0.2526.58 beta-m) it works for (1) and (2) but not yet for (3), (4), (5).

The official THREE.js website Examples does not seem to include a gamepad example (look in the section /misc).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.gamepadjs.com/) is some info regarding the gamepad state in the web.

Looks like nowadays there is still a way to wait until this gets widely supported.

Have fun!